# Could not load file or assembly 'SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, webdriverwait

I am trying to use

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("logonIdentifier")));
```

However I am getting an error Could not load file or assembly 'SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers. I am using

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TestProject.SDK" Version="0.63.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
      <PublishChromeDriver>true</PublishChromeDriver>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" Version="3.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\testForLogin\testForLogin.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It works locally but when I tried pushing it to the testproject.io I get the above error message.
[image]

I am not able to change it to the recommend selenium web driver version.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using is not .NET Core compliant.  With some restructure of the code what you need is available with

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Then take the code that used the SeleniumExtras wait helpers and change to use methods on your driver class such as

```
WebDriverWait browserWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
browserWait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("logonIdentifier")).Displayed);
```

You could easily check the properties on the driver as well, say for the Url, such as

```
const string expectedUrl = "https://www.google.com";
browserWait.Until(driver => driver.Url == expectedUrl);
```

Then go remove the package you are no longer using from your project

```
dotnet remove package DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers
```

Which funny enough is pretty much the homepage of https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/ but when you search you tend to get distracted by the SeleniumExtras project.